# How to fix test failing with "No ModelAndView found"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, applicationcontext

This class is in the top of my tests hierarchy:

```
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class ApplicationAbstractTest {
}
```

And few more test classes:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("mysql")
abstract public class AbstractControllerTest extends ApplicationAbstractTest {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }
}
```

JsonUserServiceTest:

```
@ActiveProfiles("json")
public class JsonUserServiceTest extends ApplicationAbstractTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

ContactControllerTest:

```
public class ContactControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/update-" + ID + "-contact")
                .with(userAuth(USER)))
//                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(view().name("details"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/details.jsp"));
    }
}
```

So, when I run `ContactControllerTest` along - it is successfull, and `print` method shows me:

```
Handler:
             Type = com.telecom.web.ContactController
           Method = public java.lang.String com.myApp.web.ContactController.details(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
```

But when I run all tests, so `JsonUserServiceTest` runs first, `ContactControllerTest` fails. And `print` shows:

```
Handler:
             Type = null
...
java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found
```

What is wrong in configuration? Or how troubleshoot it?

UPD:
at the same time, test like this, allways works fine:

```
public class UserControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void testRegister() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/register"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(view().name("profile"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/profile.jsp"));
    }
}
```

UPD:
There is controller's method I'm testing:

```
@GetMapping("/update-{id}-contact")
public String details(@PathVariable Integer id, ModelMap model) {
    Integer userId = AuthorizedUser.id();
    LOG.info("get contact {} for User {}", id, userId);
    Contact contact = service.get(id, userId);
    model.addAttribute("contact", contact);
    return "details";
}
```

I also have such bean:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

UPD: I've tried configure mockMvc in separate class:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Bean
    public MockMvc mockMvc() {
        return MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And added it here:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("mysql")
abstract public class AbstractControllerTest extends ApplicationAbstractTest {
```

but I've received:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be
>   null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain
>   implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.

Comment: What happens if you remove @ActiveProfiles("json") from JsonUserServiceTest and run the suit. Does ContactControllerTest work?

Comment: Yes, ContactControllerTest works in this case (but, as expected, JsonUserServiceTest does not work).

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles` takes an array. What happens if you give it `@ActiveProfiles({ "json", "mysql" })`?

Comment: It gives `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`, as I have two repository implementations, marked with different profiles: `@Profile("json")` and `@Profile("mysql")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WARN message doesn't cause the test cases to fail. It just says that  Entity manager factory is registered twice. This will only be an issue if you cluster your application using the same Entity Manager Factory. For test case run it is not a cause for concern.

The root cause of the testcase failure is in these two lines

```
 .andExpect(view().name("details"))
 .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/details.jsp"));
```

Please check if the project has a view named "details" and the forwardded url is "/WEB-INF/jsp/details.jsp"

**Update**

Could you please try this

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {


@Autowired
private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Bean
public MockMvc mockMvc() {
    return MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(springSecurityFilterChain)
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: But how it passes when I run it standalone (or with other tests with "mysql" profile)? I've updated question with method I'm testing.

Comment: Give me a hint: where do you import Filter from?

Comment: @sedub01 use import jakarta.servlet.Filter;

Answer (score 3):

Create a configuration file that will initialize mocking objects for your test cases. And put at all test case classes.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
```

It will initialize all your mocking objects only once and cached after that and reused for all test cases.

> Or if you don't want to use mocking configuration, you can directly
>   pass the actual application configuration to ContextConfiguration as
>   below

For annotation based application configuration (here AppConfig and AppConfig2 are your configuration class)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, AppConfig2.class})
```

For xml based application configuration (here appConfig.xml and appConfig2.xml are your configuration files)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:pathTo/appConfig.xml","classpath:pathTo/appConfig2.xml"})
```

Reference : [JUnit + Spring integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/)

Comment: Maybe you can tell me how to do it correctly? I updated the question with an example of my attempt.

Comment: Finally I configured `TestConfig.class` and put `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})`, and get the same error: `No ModelAndView found`

Comment: Can you please elaborate how your application initialized? Means are you using xml based configuration or Annotation based configuration. Say you are using Annotation based configuration, and you initialized your webApp in WebConfig.java then you can directly pass WebConfig.class as argument to ContextConfiguration. If you are using xml based configuration , you can directly pass xml name as argument to ContextConfiguration